# How to reduce covariance matrix (wide confidence interval) in nonlinear regression?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to do regression analysis of exponential-like equations by using the curve_fit solver. I have a good initial guess and the predicted results converge pretty well with raw data. However, the covariance matrix is extremely big and leads to a really wide confidence interval. The fitted expression is shown below:

for example  $x=12$  $y=6$
t is dependent variable and $a1_0$, $e1$, $a2_0$, $e2$ are fitted parameters:

$$ z = a1_0 \cdot e^{-e1/t}x  
 \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{a1_0\cdot e^{-e1/t}}{ a2_0\cdot e^{-e2/t}}\frac{x}{y}}\right)^{-2}$$

The initial guess for $a1_0$ and $a2_0$ are order of $10^0-10^{1}$ but the exponential terms $e^{-e1/t}$ and $e^{-e2/t}$ are order of $10^{-7}-10^{-8}$. All of these initial guesses come from experimental experience and are realistic. I am not sure whether such a difference results in the large covariance matrix. By the way, I have used lots of other solvers and other math methods and still have this problem.

Also, I have considered linearizing the $$a1_0 \cdot e^{-e1/t}$$ to $$ln(a1_0) - e1/t$$but I don't know how to linearized the complex function z.
Could everyone help me find a way to reparameterize the function z or another way to reduce the covariance matrix to get a better confidence interval? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't improve the confidence interval without obtaining more data.  What you can do is to choose parameters that individually may have "small" confidence intervals because their effects on the fit are nearly uncorrelated.  ("Small" is in quotation marks because the size of such an interval is unlikely to be commensurable with the sizes of the original intervals.)  You might find it more constructive to articulate exactly what properties of this fit are of interest and to compute confidence intervals (or regions) for them.

Comment: Hi whuber, I have increased more data points from 6-12 but still get bad confidence intervals. Also, the results of the kinetic parameters are like 10±$10^{8}$. I am not sure how many data point is needed to get good confidence interval.